# 400 bad request when accessing server via https

Tags: nginx, docker

Im using Portainer to run Atlassian Jira instances. I would like to be able to access each container via tpg.xyz/containerName (in this case jira). Currently I have this working with the exception of it throwing an error of `400 Bad Request - The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTP Port`.

This happens when I input the url `https://tpg.xyz/jira`, it is then changed to `tpg.xyz:443/jira`. If I then add https:// to the beginning of the url It will take me to the homepage of jira. however each time I navigate to a new page the https:// is removed from the url and I am met with the same error 400.

Any ideas what ive missed?

Edit: realised the config had my domain in it so I may aswell add it to the question just in case someone poking around could help.

Heres my Nginx config

```
server {
  server_name docker.tpg.xyz tpg.xyz www.tpg.xyz; # managed by Certbot

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }


    location /jira{
           proxy_pass            http://127.0.0.1:8081/jira;
           proxy_read_timeout    300;
          proxy_connect_timeout 300;
           proxy_redirect        off;
           proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Host $host;
           proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Server $host;
           proxy_set_header      X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
           proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
 }

        listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server; # managed by Certbot
  #  listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/tpg.xyz/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/tpg.xyz/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = docker.tpg.xyz) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = www.tpg.xyz) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = tpg.xyz) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80 ;
    listen [::]:80 ;
    server_name docker.tpg.xyz tpg.xyz www.tpg.xyz;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot






}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I had set an env variable wrong because I hadn't initially planned to use https when setting up the jira instance in the first place. I had set the env variable CATALINA_CONNECTOR_SCHEME to http. Changing it to https has solved the problem